# how to load usercontrol into splitcontainer.panel2?

Tags: c#, .net

Learning .NET:

I have a form with a split container, I want to load usercontrol into panel2, but

```
splitContainer1.Panel2.add(..)
```

Doesn't work.

EDIT, working now:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1 myUserCont = new UserControl1();
        splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(myUserCont);
    }
```

- How do I load a usercontrol into it?
- Will data bindnings in usercontrol work when loaded into panel?
- Into panel1, there will be a tree-view for (data bound) object type navigation. Am I on the right path?

regards,

/T

Comment: Aside from the correct solution givein in answers: all public methods in .Net begin with a capital letter by convention, so you won't find any "add" but rather "Add" method in .Net. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code:

```
splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(...)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(utcMyTest)
```

to unload:

```
 splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Remove(utcMyTest)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Shouldn't it be new controls[] ? (square brackets, not round ones?)

Comment: please comment regarding bullets 2/3.